# SharePoint 2013 Multi-Lingual content conversion

Tags: multilingual

**Scenario:**

User from France (using French as language) post a comment in the SharePoint 2013 default blog site comment box of  with French language, then user from Mexico (using language as Spanish) should see the French comment in Spanish language.

Is it possible achieve this requirement with SharePoint Out of the Box features?

Comment: I doubt there is any SharePoint OOTB way to achieve this. But the easiest solution will be that the end user use the browser translator. Will be interesting to explore more about maybe some plugin can automate it.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
We suggested with Browser Translation only 2,000,000 Characters/month is free with Microsoft translation service.